# Fill template with image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create a design for a print, I have been sent an Adobe Illustrator template file with a an outline of the printable area which I need to add my design to.

I don't have much experience with Illustrator and I was looking for a kind of live paint bucket tool but for placing an image inside the wire frame template. I basically just want to crop my image into the template, but I have no idea how.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a **clipping mask**.

Draw a rectangle (or any shape) which covers the area you want the image to **show** in. Place the shape above the image.

Select the image and the shape, and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu.